# How do we align the output generated by IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM to 4 bytes automatically?

Tags: arm, hex, alignment, iar, dword

I'm trying to get the output .hex file to have an automatic alignment to 4 bytes every time it is generated.
Using ielftool would require me to have an additional manual step to calculate how many bytes I want to add so it's of no use.
Also, setting the fill to the maximum file size would fix this but would mean that we would have to download the whole size (i.e. 256KB) even when the actual binary file is very small (i.e. 5KB).

Comment: Please clarify: is the problem with the beginning or the end of the binary?

Comment: The problem is at the end of the file, if you can say so. I would like to have it ending at a location multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: Memory fill allows you to set end address for the fill. As a workaround, you could set it to reasonable upper limit, for example 8kB or the nearest end of flash sector.

Comment: Also, you could use use project post-build feature to invoke script automatically at the end of compilation to execute multiple ielftool commands. I have used custom Python script to do that in the past projects.

Comment: You're correct and that is what I'm doing now, but those options require me to set the size of the final binary to a fixed value. 
What I wanted was to have it to whatever the compiled code size is (not fixed) but still setting a small padding in the end (if necessary) so that it is always aligned.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define a block with `end alignment` for the linker configuration.

One ".icf" stock configuration could be:

```
place in FLASH_region { readonly };
```

Suggested general solution, based on the stock configuration:

```
define block ROBLOCK with alignment = 4, end alignment = 4 { readonly };
place in FLASH_region { block ROBLOCK };
```

Using a block with end alignment should dynamically adjust as the application grows.